# When should you use layout="fill" versus layout="responsive" on amp-video in amp-story? What is the difference between the two?

Tags: video, amp-html, amp-story

Here are two suggested code snippets from the amp documentation for the amp-video tag.  Which implementation produces a faster, more reliable outcome under most circumstances? What is the difference between the two snippets in terms of performance and UX?

**first code snipped with template="fill" and layout="fill"**
 - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#children

```
<amp-story-page id="cover">
  <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
    <amp-video layout="fill" src="background.mp4" poster="background.png" muted autoplay></amp-video>
  </amp-story-grid-layer>
  <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
    <h1>These are the Top 5 World's Most...</h1>
    <p>Jon Bersch</p>
    <p>May 18</p>
  </amp-story-grid-layer>
  <amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
    <amp-img grid-area="bottom-third" src="a-logo.svg" width="64" height="64"></amp-img>
  </amp-story-grid-layer>
</amp-story-page>
```

**second code snippet with template="fill" and layout="responsive"**
 - https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-video

```
<amp-video controls
  width="640"
  height="360"
  layout="responsive"
  poster="images/kitten-playing.png">
  <source src="videos/kitten-playing.webm"
    type="video/webm" />
  <source src="videos/kitten-playing.mp4"
    type="video/mp4" />
  <div fallback>
    <p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one has direct implications on performance; this only changes the layout on the page.  Additionally, the `template="fill"` attribute is actually special in that it overrides the sizing of the element.

So, I actually believe that the end result here will be the same regardless of the value of the `layout` attribute, as long as the `template="fill"` attribute is set on the containing layer.